# What does this icon mean in the Powerline shell git segment?

Tags: git, powerline

I recently switched from using [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) only in Vim to also using it in zsh and tmux. Using the default configuration for everything so far.

In the shell prompt for a git repo, can anyone explain what the information shown next to the branch name is? (in yellow in the screenshot)

[image: Powerline git information]

It doesn't seem to be number of commits ahead/behind, which was my first thought.

I'm using the patched version of Inconsolata so hopefully all the icons are displaying as intended.

Answer (score 2):

It's the number of stashes.

After seeing the number increase and decrease while working I was able to figure this out.